# Turn 3 column table in 2-dimensional matrix in MySQL

Tags: mysql, tabular

I have a table that looks like this:

```
color | size | deliverytime
--------------------
red   |   S  |  1
red   |   M  |  3
red   |   L  |  5
black |   S  |  2
black |   M  |  4
black |   L  |  6
```

I would now like the table to transform to something like this:

```
      S | M | L
      ---------
  red 1 | 3 | 5
black 2 | 4 | 6
```

The background is: the delivery time for, say, a T-shirt, is different, depending on color and size. Not every color is available in every size and the sizes are not fixed, e.g. womens sizes could start at 36,38,40 instead of S, M, L.
So what puzzles me here is how to turn the values of the first table dynamically into the column captions of the second.

The list of valid values for sizes is too big to make just a big table out of it.

I would like to do this in MySQL, e.g. as a function. The only other option I can think of is doing it in another language, since the output will be in HTML. I don't really know how I should Google this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do there if I get it right is to group by color and size. You can get same data just by adding `GROUP BY color, size` at the end of your query. Then you can just format your data when outputting html.

To get the most of sql you may want to avoid looking at it in terms of a data matrix.